# Which of these is correct when using hubiera sido & fuera, and what is the difference between the two verbs

Tags: gramática, verbos

Which of these is correct when using *hubiera sido* & *fuera*, and what is the difference between the two verbs?

> 1: Si el florero no **hubiera sido caro**, lo habría comprado para mi
>   madre.
>
> 2: Si el florero no **fuera caro**, lo habría comprado para mi madre.

I was told that the second one should be "lo compraría para mi madre".

Are the two sentences correct?

Can I switch "lo habría comprado" for "lo compraría"? and what will be the difference in meaning?

And maybe an explanation between the two verb forms if they are correct?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Mixed conditionals** are used both in English language and in Spanish language.
Its usage depends on the time reference.

The forms:

> 1. Si el florero no **hubiera sido** caro, lo **habría comprado** para mi madre.
> 2. Si el florero no **fuera** caro, lo **habría comprado** para mi madre.

are both grammatical with different meanings.
The first one is used to speculate about an imaginary result of things that didn't happen. (An impossible situation that didn't happen in the past.)
The second one shows a present situation with a result that didn't happen.

Both implications are shown as follows:

> 1. Si el florero no **hubiera sido** caro, lo **habría comprado** para mi madre. (El florero **era** caro, así que no lo **compré**. — This shows two past actions that are imaginary. —)
> 2. Si el florero no **fuera** caro, lo **habría comprado** para mi madre. (El florero **es** caro, así que no lo **compré**. — This shows a present situation, the vase is still expensive, so the consequence is shown in the past. —)

If we want to speculate about a situation where the result remains in the present, we use in the second clause *lo compraría* (in #2), but this does not move the result in the past.

Answer (score 2):

### Would have bought vs Would buy

This is what it boils down to at the end of the day.

> If the vase weren't so expensive, I would buy it.
>
> If the vase weren't so expensive, I would have bought it.

See how the first sentence retains the present time?  The second sentence suggests that the opportunity to buy the vase has passed.

Another example

> If I weren't afraid of heights, I would jump.
>
> If I weren't afraid of heights, I would have jumped

In conclusion, the [perfect conditional tense](http://www.spanishdict.com/topics/show/104) can't just be replaced willy nilly with [plain conditional tense](http://www.spanishdict.com/topics/show/97),.

Answer (score 1):

in those examples, "hubiera sido caro" refers to the past and "fuera caro" refers to the present it still is expensive.

And yes on the second example you should use "lo compraría para mi madre" in order to keep the same time on the sentence.

Comment: I disagree with the last part. "Si el florero no fuera caro, lo habría comprado para mi madre" is perfectly grammmatical: it means the vase is still expensive. With "lo compraría" you're saying the action is in the present. That changes drastically the meaning of the original sentence, where you can't buy that vase anymore. If you say "me habría comprado una casa si no hubieran sido tan caras", you're saying houses aren't expensive anymore, or that the situation is different somehow. "Me habría comprado una casa si no fueran tan caras" is also correct and it implies houses are still expensive.

Comment: Second one is perfectly grammatical. More details should be added to this answer.

Answer (score 1):

1. Si el florero no **hubiera sido caro**, lo habría comprado para mi madre.
2. Si el florero no **fuera caro**, lo habría comprado para mi madre.

In **example 1**, you are using the "third conditional", which is used to say something that it is impossible to change at the moment: it was possible in the past, but it's not anymore now.

- The **third conditional**, *in Spanish*, is formed with: Si + pluperfect subjunctive + simple/compose conditional. In *English*, the equivalent is: If + Past Perfect tense  would/could/might + have + past participle.

In the **example 2**, you are using the "second conditional" which is used to say an action that it can be possible.

- The **second conditional**, *in Spanish*, is formed with: Si + imperfect subjunctive + simple/compose conditional. In *English*, the equivalent is: If + Past Simple would / could / might + verb.

Comment: What can be possible?

Comment: I'm not familiar with the terms s second and third conditional. Could you explain?

Comment: @Yay the action can be possible, guifa, I've edited my question, explaining this :)

Comment: But that's precisely what I think is wrong with this answer and the other one. In both sentences you are saying you didn't buy that vase, and you can't change that. The difference between them isn't about that, but about the fact the vase is still there and still expensive in 2, but something changed in 1. Also, 1 is a third conditional but 2 is a *mixed conditional*, not a 2nd conditional. A 2nd conditional would be "Si el florero no fuera caro, lo **compraría** para mi madre", which indeed means the action is still possible.

Comment: This fails to answer the question.

Comment: @Yay you seem to be saying something very similar to what I say...However, in Spanish, we don't really have the "mixed conditional" as in English. Anyway, I accept your comments if you are Spanish professors, otherwise, I still see my answer as correct (and even a bit trivial if you can check this grammar in a Spanish book)

Comment: Llámalo condicional mixto, llámalo combinación de tipo 2 y tipo 3, no tiene importancia. En todo caso, el tipo 2 sería "si no fuera caro, lo compraría". "Si no fuera caro, lo habría comprado" expresa una realidad distinta que tu respuesta no explica. La diferencia a la que me refiero la explica Ustanak en su respuesta. Ese es el meollo de la pregunta.

Comment: la diferencia no es simplemente que una acción ya es imposible de realizar mientras que la otra es todavía posible? Y si profundizamos más, la diferencia también es la estructura gramatical que he puesto en mi respuesta. Pero bueno, para gustos colores...

Comment: @yay, por cierto, lo malo es que habéis valorado mi respuesta negativamente sin dar una explicación coherente para que pudiera corregirla dado el caso, y ahora la gente va a pensar que es incorrecta cuando a mí, ese razonamiento me ayudó a aprender la estructura gramatical en inglés. si haces una simple búsqueda en google, verás si hay algo incorrecto en lo que he dicho.

Comment: No, ambas son imposibles de realizar. Al decir "lo habría comprado" estás diciendo que no lo compraste, y eso ya no se puede cambiar. A lo mejor lo podrías comprar en el futuro, pero el hecho de que no lo compraste en su momento es irreparable. La diferencia entre amas estriba en que en el primer caso el precio del jarrón se sitúa en el pasado y en el segundo se enfatiza que el jarrón todavía es caro. Te estamos diciendo que esa es la razón por la que tu respuesta no contesta correctamente la pregunta, y que por eso ha recibido votos negativos. (Y esa diferencia sí se puede ver en Google.)

Comment: @BehindTheSciences Tu respuesta simplente no responde. Mencionas que el segundo caso corresponde a un *segundo condicional* pero en realidad mezcla dos tiempos. Eso en inglés se conoce como condicional mixto. Está claro que en español esa distinción no se conoce, pero se usa bastante ese tipo de combinación y depende bastante de la referencia temporal. Tu respuesta se rige a reglas, pues no explicas el porqué de que la segunda afirmación sea o no un segundo condicional.

Comment: @Ustanak como quieras...